# How to do a nucleic acid or genome and amino acid search

Tags: genetics, amino-acids

I have been looking to find a database where i can search for genome and amino acid search. Are there any open source databases available for the same.

Comment: Welcome to Bio.SE! What attempts to answer this question have you already taken? We ask that all question posters here attempt to search for an answer to their own question and explicitly indicate what research they've already done, what they learned, and what is still confusing or unknown to them. Our goal is not to simply be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way :). Please take a moment to edit your post with this additional detail, and it will likely be received more positively by our community. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In my experience the most popular sequence database is https://www.ensembl.org/ (other databases are available, eg. [NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/)).  If you have a sequence of either nucleotides or amino acids that you want to find matches for then the [BLAST/BLAT search](https://www.ensembl.org/Multi/Tools/Blast?db=core) is probably what you want.

Comment: Really? Primary in what sense? Ever heard of NCBI?

Comment: I thought about that when writing.  I work in Europe, and I do not know anyone who uses NCBI rather than ensembl.  I shall alter my answer to indicate others are available.

Comment: I work in Europe too and have worked at EMBL. However I do not know anyone who uses ENSEMBL for database searching. Part of the reason is that the ENSEMBL interfaces have always been so much worse than those at NCBI because the latter had the money to make it a priority whereas I suspect EBI had neither the motivation nor the money. The worst on-line experience I have ever had was trying to submit RNAseq data to ENA.